# Intellij file tab missing (but not module!)

Tags: intellij-idea

I cloned a repo from github only to find that the intellij project window is missing!

[image]

But! I have a not missing a project module (like other people on are)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is just that you're not showing the project tab!

To show the project tab:

1. Press the [image] icon in the bottom left of the screen
2. On the left side of your window, a bar should appear, press the:

[image] If it's not already pressed.

3. (optional) You may need to change to "Project view", on the top part of the project window there should be a little drop down, select "Project"

That should do it!  I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you that did help!

Comment: Shortcut: Cmd+1 or Alt +1 in windows